# Automatic redirection to a servlet from a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to auto redirect to a servlet from a JSP page?

I know it's possible to do this to another JSP like this:

```
 <% response.addHeader("Refresh","4;./nexPage.jsp"); %>
```

This code will redirect to *nexPage.jsp* after 4 seconds.

But I want it to redirect to a given servlet instead.

Comment: Have you tried just putting the Servlet's URL instead of `./nexPage.jsp`?

Comment: use response.sendRedirect("./nexPage.jsp") instead

Comment: What is the servlet context?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, but it giv me an error: `HTTP Status 500 - ` .... `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

Comment: @AsmeJust so you need to check the servlet codez

Comment: Exactly. I'm with @user2511414. Your servlet seem to have a problem.

Comment: @user2511414 actually, i create a link: `<a href="./SeanceServlet?matId=${mat.matId}">Go to NextPage</a>` that send me to the servlet which redirect me to nextPage.jsp and this work well but I want the process to be automatic so that the user won't have to click to the link to go to NextPage.jsp. you see?

Comment: @AsmeJust I see buddy, first if servlet is just like a forward thing, so why don't you redirect it directly to nextPage and omit the servlet? but if servlet should do something then redirect, you need to invoke request.getRequestDispatcher("./nextPage.jsp").forward(request,response).

Comment: becareful when you forward the request from the servlet to another path, because the socket is still open, also its output stream, so don not write any content that makes conflict with the forward target

Comment: @user2511414 well in fact, the servlet have some data to fetch from the database before. that's why. actually, I use `request.getRequestDispatcher("./nextPage.jsp").forward(request,response)` in the servlet

Comment: @AsmeJust did your problem solved? by the way, if you want to pass something to the target JSP page, you would add the objects by request.addPaarameter("name","value") in servlet, and get the data by value=response.getAttribute("name") in jsp :D

Comment: @user2511414 well Actually, I dont have problem, It work well, ... It's just that process to let the user click to the nextPage link I want automate. you see?

Comment: @AsmeJust of course I've got the problem dude, so did the solution helpful for you? or you have still problem with automate redirecting, if you share your code, I would edit it to the desired code.

Comment: @user2511414 ok cool, Am adding the code

Comment: Does this work: `<%response.addHeader("Refresh","4;./SeanceServlet?matId="+ mat.getMatId()); %>` ?

Comment: @user2511414 well the code is a lil bit long to put them all here, so I Put It here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cc5vyetcu6vb10n/CTN.zip)

Comment: @acdcjunior no, it give me lot of error...

Comment: @AsmeJust Okay, thanks, you have done everything good, but it seems the SuccessRedirected is used for notification, called by NewSeanceAjouterServlet,so just omit this page, forward the result directly to SeanceServlet, just change the request dispatcher path in NewSeanceAjouterServlet to "/CTN/SeanceServlet", try and reply about the response

Comment: @user2511414 Thank you very much... That's what I did before BUT: if I omit SuccessRedirected, I get a duplication when I refresh the "NextPage" ... I made a post about it here: stackoverflow.com/questions/17377041/… ... but as I didn't solve that problem either, I created that SuccessRedirected page to avoid user to refresh and duplicate the last submitted data. You see now?

Comment: @AsmeJust okay okay, so in the NewSeanceAjouterServlet, remove the dispatching process, and use this instead response.sendRedirect("/CTN/SeanceServlet"); it ensures you user redirect to the SeanceServlet, and also in SeanceServlet check that if attributes are null redirect the user to desired page as above code :D, also check this and response, I have to ensure at least I was helpful today :D

Comment: Well you're are unbelievably helpful for me... I think I already try that but, am gonna try again.

Comment: @AsmeJust Oh, I'm sorry, I've forgot to tell, you, if you want to redirect, so you need to set the parameter in session scope(no with request.setAttribute()), simply use request.getSession().addAttribute("name","value"), and also in SeanceServlet get it with request.getSession().getAtrribute("name"), BUT DON'T forget to clear the session after getting value(avoiding of duplicate of data in referesh) by request.getSession().removeAttribute("name"), I'm really sorry, sorry, please try it

Comment: @user2511414 Don't be sorry, I haven't found a solution yet but let me tell you: you're the most helpful guy I've meet in stack I can say. Thank you very much for your effort... Between I get error again java.lang.NumberFormatException: null with `response.sendRedirect("/CTN/SeanceServlet");` .... I have never use session but I think It's time ... sorry for being too noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check with this.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=/servleturl">
```

This will redirect to the given servlet url after 5 seconds.
place this tag between your head tag. But i think this is not SEO friendly.

Comment: Hello, Well it worked: I just added this code like you said: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=./SeanceServlet?matiereId=${matiere.matiereId}">`...

Answer (score -1):

response.sendRedirect("servletname");